# Retrieve array webmethod into listview Android

Tags: android, arrays, web-services, android-listview

Does anyone know how to retrieve from webmethod array to display on listview?
This is my WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public info[] retrieveInfo (String code){
SQLCon.. 
.
.
info [] a = new info [count];
cmd.. 
.
.

while(reader.Read()){
    a[i].id = (int)reader["ID"];
    a[i].description = (string)reader["Description"];
    a[i].date = (string)reader["Date"];
    a[i].url = (string)reader["URL"];
    a[i].name = (string)reader["Name"];
    i++
}
reader.Close();
conn.Close();

Array.Reverse(a);
return a;
```

I only managed to figure out up until here. After that I am totally lost and in addition I want to put all the return into listview2.

```
//SOAP
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty("code", code);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true; // Set this variable to true for
                            // compatibility with what seems to be the default encoding for.Net-Services.

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    System.out.println(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
           androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
           Log.i("myApp", response.toString());
           System.out.println("response " +response);

    }catch(SocketException ex)
    {
       Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } 
} 
}
```

Comment: even I am interested to know the answer to tis question. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved...

My XML code is,

`<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@android:id/list"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" />`

The class should extend `ListActivity` instead of simple Activity.

The code in try block is,

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);    
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelop = new     
        SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelop.dotNet=true;
        soapEnvelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        request.addProperty("authenid",authenid);
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelop);     

        SoapObject result;
        result=(SoapObject)soapEnvelop.getResponse();
        int cnt = result.getPropertyCount();
        String[] ary = new String[cnt];

        for(Integer i1=0;i1<cnt;i1++)
        {
            ary[i1]=result.getProperty(i1).toString();

              for(Integer i2=0;i2<=i1;i2++)
                  {
                  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ary);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                  } 
        }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I wish to add ratings to this and the items should be retrieved from webservices... what code should be altered in this above code.